# Mongodb- Delete some of the array elements within embedded document

Tags: mongodb

There are 2 kinds of documents.
Type 1. Documents contain the either MCN-ONE, MCN-TWO, MCN-THREE(or all 3) along with other values 
2. Another type of documents do not contain any among these values. 
First, I would like to get the documents having those array elements(either 1 or 2 or all 3). Then I want to keep MCN-ONE,MCN-TWO,MCN-THREE and delete all others (CCC-ALARM..etc) in bulk. Could you help to write the query? The below mentioned document falls in type 1.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d721f5296eaaafd1df263e8"),
"assetId" : "ALL",
"createdTime" : ISODate("2019-09-06T08:56:50.065Z"),
"default" : false,
"lastUpdatedTime" : ISODate("2019-09-06T09:11:35.463Z"),
"preferences" : {
    "MCN-TWO" : [ 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "MCN-ONE" : [ 
        "TEST", 
        "TEST", 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "MCN-THREE" : [ 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "CCC-ALARM" : [ 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "SSD-ALARM" : [ 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "TFT-ALARM" : [ 
        "TEST", 
        "TEST"
    ],
    "REC-WARN" : []
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic approach would be to transform `preferences` subdocument with `$objectToArray`, then filter desired elements with `$filter`, `$map` or `$reduce` and transform back with `$arrayToObject`. However, your requirement is "get elements MCN-ONE,MCN-TWO,MCN-THREE". The simple way is to update element `preferences` and replace just with conten of `MCN-ONE,MCN-TWO,MCN-THREE`. It can be done by this aggregation:

In order to filter documents, set the `$match` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
               $or: [
                  { $ne: ["$preferences.MCN-ONE", null] },
                  { $ne: ["$preferences.MCN-TWO", null] },
                  { $ne: ["$preferences.MCN-THREE", null] }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         $set: {
            preferences: {
               $mergeObjects: [
                  { "MCN-ONE": "$preferences.MCN-ONE" },
                  { "MCN-TWO": "$preferences.MCN-TWO" },
                  { "MCN-THREE": "$preferences.MCN-THREE" }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Can you explain this query.?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looks I have not explained properly my use case.Updated the question.

Comment: According to what you have asked, the solution is still the same.

Comment: But i suspect, the above query would update the type 2 documents as well which i don't want to touch. Am i wrong here?

Comment: I am getting this error when run in robo3t. "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",
 "code" : 40324,
 "codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed

Comment: See my answer. `$set` was added in MongoDB 4.2, use `$addFields` instead.

Comment: Hi, This query processes the data and returns computed results. But if i run find(), data remains same. How to update all the returned records in the db?

Comment: Use `db.collection.updateMany({}, [<aggregation pipeline>])`

Comment: Hi, looks like aggregation pipeline feature available in v4.2 onwards. What is the syntax for v3.6.9?